# Handling variable JSON response in Angular template

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to handle dynamic JSON responses with a single angular template. Below are two examples of the same template, but different JSON responses (somewhat similar). I'm trying to figure out how to handle both (and quite possibly more) of these responses in the same template. **Essentially how do I handle UNKNOWN levels in a json response?**

http://plnkr.co/edit/1H9AfwUYvcYVEBmBb0Ln?p=preview

```
{"book": {
        "title": "Book Title",
        "chapters": [
            {
                "title": "Chapter One",
                "units": [
                    {
                        "title" : "Unit One",
                        "sections": [
                            {"title" : "Section One"},
                            {"title" : "Section Two"},
                            {"title" : "Section Three"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"title" : "Unit Two"},
                    {"title" : "Unit Three"}
                ]
            },
            {"title": "Chapter Two"},
            {"title": "Chapter Three"}
        ]
    }};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8S6iCrF3A72MNEpKEhMu?p=preview

```
{"book": {
        "title": "Book Title",
        "chapters": [
            {
                "title": "Chapter One",
                "sections": [
                            {"title" : "Section One"},
                            {"title" : "Section Two"},
                            {"title" : "Section Three"}
                        ]
            },
            {"title": "Chapter Two"},
            {"title": "Chapter Three"}
        ]
    }};
```

Template:

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in book">
    {{item.title}}
    <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="chapter in item.chapters">
            {{chapter.title}}
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="unit in chapter.units">
              {{unit.title}}
              <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="section in unit.sections">
                  {{section.title}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Show your code here in the question. Just showing some data and a link doesn't cut it. We should be  able to review your issue in a stand alone question without having to go off site to multiple links. There really isn't even a question here

Comment: point out what is ur question

Comment: so what is the actual issue? How to handle unknown levels?

Comment: @charlietfl correct!

Comment: There are lots of examples around. You are looking for a recursive tree. The main thing is to name the nested property names the same for `children` so at each level you can do `if children.length`. Can put the sub headings like `chapter` in same name properties also at each level....other properties like `text` or `content`. keep structure consistent and it will all fall into place

Comment: Oh... and if structure is identical at each level, you use a repeating  nested directive. One template for all levels

Comment: Thanks for the right direction on how to tackle this issue @charlietfl looking into your mentioned nested directives now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
  {{ book.title }}
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="chapter in book.chapters" ng-if="book.chapters.length > 0">
      {{ chapter.title }}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="unit in chapter.units" ng-if="chapter.units.length > 0">
          {{ unit.title }}
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="section in unit.sections">
              {{ section.title }}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```